# Fixed div Goes through Top of Page

Tags: html, css

In my website, I have added a top navigation bar. The page acts like the top of the text is where the top of the tabs within the div begin and cuts the top of them off.

Go to [my website](http://www.familyfrat.com/) (familyfrat.com) and look at the main tabs on the top to see an example.

The CSS for the top navigation div is:

```
    .nav-bar{
      background-color:#ac5930;
      height:4.5%;
      width:100%;
      position:fixed;
      left:0px;
      top:0px;
    }
```

The following is the code for the tabs within the div:

```
    #tab-family,#tab-grouplets,#tab-support,#tab-home,#tab-myacc{
    background-color:#ac5930;
    padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
    color:#29150b;
    font-size:100%;
    font-family:arial;
    display:inline;
    cursor:default;
    height:100%;
    transition:.3s;
    -moz-transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
    -ms-transition:.3s;
    -o-transition:.3s;
}
#tab-family:hover,#tab-grouplets:hover,#tab-support:hover,#tab-home:hover,#tab-myacc:hover{
    background-color:#8a4726;
    transition:.3s;
    -moz-transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
    -ms-transition:.3s;
    -o-transition:.3s;
}
#tab-family:active,#tab-grouplets:active,#tab-support:active,#tab-home:active,#tab-myacc:active{
    background-color:#532b17;
    transition:.3s;
    -moz-transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
    -ms-transition:.3s;
    -o-transition:.3s;
}
```

Comment: To those who rate it down, please tell me why or give me help before you rate it as a bad question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add a `min-height` in pixels or in % for the navigation bar, as well as a `z-index` that makes it appear above all other elements in the DOM.

Comment: I changed it, but it still sticks above the page margins.